# Python 3 incorrectly converting "0x0000" string into hex

Tags: python, string, hex

I am pulling data from a database, and one of the columns constantly has hex data starting with "0x". The end goal is to simply write all the data from this table into a pipe delimited file that is read by another system. naturally, this triggers Python to think its a hex value and tries to convert it. Here is a snippet of my code.

```
for row in cur.execute(sql):
    for x in range(len(row)):
                    
                    if(str(row[x]) is None or str(row[x])=='None'):
                        row[x]=""
                    if(len(row)-1==x):
                       
                        f.write(str(row[x]))
                    else:
                        f.write(str(row[x])+"|")
```

row[x] can be an int, string, datetime, etc..  The str() converts it into a string, but when it hits a cell that contains "0x0000" it converts the hex into b'\x00\x00'.  I want the value to simply show "0x0000". The data is being stored in the database as varbinary.

Comment: Can you show us what the value is without any operations? Is it actually stored as “0x0000”? I have a feeling the database stores it as a hex value, not as a string

Comment: the data is being stored as 'varbinary'

Comment: ok, so it’s being stored as a binary, sql is doing something to it. It doesn’t seem like it is str’s fault. You should try and specify the data type in your table configuration as char/varchar.

Comment: The datatype has been added to the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if the value may be [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) instance, in which case you can convert it to a string of hex digits by calling it's [hex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) method, and prefix the result with '0x' to get the string representation that you want.

```py
bs = b'\x00\x00'
s = '0x' + bs.hex()  # '0x0000'
```

Your code would then look something like this:

```py
for row in cur.execute(sql):
    for x in range(len(row)):
                    
        if(str(row[x]) is None or str(row[x])=='None'):
            row[x]=""

        elif isinstance(row[x], bytes):
            row[x] = '0x' + row[x].hex()

        if(len(row)-1==x):       
            f.write(str(row[x]))
        else:
            f.write(str(row[x])+"|")
```